# Resolving symbols in static libraries -- When does it happen?

Tags: c++, dll, linker, msvc12

### The Error

I received an `unresolved external symbol` in a dependency while building a project, and I want to understand why this wasn't a problem earlier on.

### The Background Information

The project dependency graph is like so:

```
FRCUserProgram.exe
 |--wpilibC++Sim.lib 
  |--gazebo.exe
  |-- gazebo.lib
   |-- gazebo_common.lib (uses freeimage in Image.cc.obj)
    |-- FreeImaged.lib
```

So, I have the header and static libraries for FreeImage.

I build gazebo_common, explicitly linking statically against FreeImaged.lib

I build gazebo, explicitly linking statically against FreeImage.lib **and** gazebo_common.lib

I build wpilibC++Sim, explicitely linking statically against gazebo.lib and gazebo_common.lib but **not** FreeImaged.lib

I build my FRCUserProgram, explicitely linking statically against gazebo.lib, gazebo_common.lib, and FreeImaged.lib

However, when I do this, I get and `unresolved external symbol __imp_FreeImage_Initialize` coming from `Image.cc.obj`.

### What I did to investigate

Now, using the magical `dumpbin /SYMBOLS` command, I can clearly see that `FreeImaged.lib` contains the symbol `FreeImage_Initialize`, **not** the symbol `__imp_FreeImage_Initialize`. I know that the __imp_ tells me it an function meant to be imported from a DLL. However, everything should be linking statically, so whatever put that symbol into `Image.cc.obj` did it wrong.

To fix this, I can either link `FRCUserProgram.exe` against the dynamic library of FreeImage, or I can rebuild gazebo_common (and therefore Image.cc.obj) with the variable `FREEIMAGE_LIB` defined, which will prevent the __declspec(import) and __imp_ from being prepended to the symbol.

Most of all, there is no Dll, ANYWHERE. It doesn't exist. I don't have it. I'm trying to use the static library `FreeImaged.lib`. So I think the correct thing to do is defining `FREEIMAGE_LIB`, so that `Image.cc.obj`gets the right symbols built into it. Of course this works, but I don't understand why this wasn't a problem earlier!

## The Question:

Why did those symbols need to be resolved for FRCUserProgram.exe and not gazebo.exe?

Comment: The compiler cannot know up front whether you are going to link it statically or use the DLL.  That happens later.  Just look at FreeImage.h in your text editor and it will be instantly obvious how it knows.  Note the usage of the FREEIMAGE_LIB macro.  It goes wrong the way you describe when it is not #defined, very easy to forget of course.

Comment: Your first sentence confuses me. When I specify the macro `FREEIMAGE_LIB` it knows up front I'm using the static library. Are you saying that when building a DLL (and not using that macro), it just __assumes__ I have the DLL somewhere and never needs to resolve the external references? If that were the case, why resolve them for building my FRCUserProgram?

Comment: No.  Nothing to do with building a DLL, the macro matters when you compile *any* code that includes FreeImage.h.  The #define must be present when build gazebo_common as well.

Comment: That's case I understand. But let's say I forget, and **don't** use the macro. The symbols will have `__imp_` in front, fine. When I go to build `gazebo.exe` shouldn't it have to look up those symbols in `FreeImaged.lib` (which won't be there)? It clearly doesn't....and yet when I go to build `FRCUserProgram.exe` it decides it needs to find them! Why?

Comment: A .lib file is just a bag of object files, the linker is not involved.  So you can never get a linker error from building a library.  Any problems with compiler settings don't reveal themselves until you try to link the library.

Comment: I'm not talking about building a library, I'm talking about building **executables**. I can build the `gazebo.exe` executable but not my `FRCUserProgram.exe`. Both of them link to the `gazebo_common` and `FreeImaged` library.